# express.static() won't work to fetch images

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am new at programming, sorry if the question is stupid. I could not find anything to help me online.

On Angular, I have the URL of the image to fetch from the server side.
If the URL is

```
http://localhost:3000/h.jpg
```

and I have

```
app.use(express.static('backend/adImages'));
```

everything works fine. 
If I change the path to

```
http://localhost:3000/adImages/e.jpg
```

and the code to

```
app.use('/adImages', express.static('backend/adImages'));
```

I cannot visualize the image.

my path is

```
C:\Users\PupoZz\Desktop\mean\personal\eTrex\backend\adImages
```

is my path. The server.js file is in the eTrex folder

another thing. If I run the server to show the database. I can click the link and open the image:

```
_id "5e80643f1bf2d90d685e3e66"
title   "e"
description "e"
location    "e"
postedBy    "null"
image   "http://localhost:3000/adImages/e.jpg"
__v 0
```

on my inspector I can see

```
"<img _ngcontent-vlp-c2=\"\" class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"http://localhost:3000/adimages/e.jpg\" style=\"display: none !important;\">"
```

any idea?

thanks
Marco

Comment: I will ask the silly question.  Your first example references `h.jpg` which you say works.  Your second example references `e.jpg`.  Is there an `e.jpg` in the `backend/adImages` directory?

Comment: I have both of them. well spotted though

Comment: Then, it seems likely something is not quite as you think because in your second example, a request for `http://localhost:3000/adImages/e.jpg` would find `e.jpg` in `backend/adImages` via your `express.static()` line of code.  So, either there's some other route before it causing a problem or the URL isn't really what you think it is.

Comment: is there a way to check?  It is curious that I cannot see any broken image icon (like when the link does not work), just white!

Comment: Look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and it will show you all the requests and all the responses for a given page (you have to open the network tab and then reload the page) and you can see if the image is successfully being served or not.

Comment: the image from http://localhost:3000/adImages/e.jpg is not on the network in both cases, when I use 1) app.use(express.static('backend/adImages'));
2)app.use('/adimages', express.static('backend/adImages'));

Comment: What is the full disk path to e.jpg is located?  What is the full disk path your file that contains the `app.use(express.static())` statement?  We need to know both full paths in order to know what path you should be using in your middleware and how to specify a relative path to it correctly.  Also, do you have any other routes or middleware before your `app.use(express.static())` statement?

Comment: I edited the post to show the path. I have before the express.static statement:
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
  });

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to you guys, I checked the right place. It seems that firefox blocked the image because it was in the adimages folder.
I just changed the folder name to "images"!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const path = require('path');
//
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'backend', 'adImages');
```

if the file is in the backend folder, exclude the backend

```
const path = require('path');
//
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'adImages');
```

1)

```
-server.js
-/backend
---/adImages
```

2)

```
-/backend
---server.js
---/adImages
```

Comment: it does not work. As it happens using "app.use('/adImages', express.static('backend/adImages'));", angular won't load the image.   IT is curious that I cannot see any broken image icon (like when the link does not work), just white!

Comment: try to open image buy url, if image appears, that mean problems with angular

Comment: if I go to page info => media, I can see the image using "app.use('/adImages', express.static('backend/adImages'));" If the problem is Angular, what I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app.use(express.static('backend'));
```

And more importantly don't forget to restart your node.js server after the fact.

Happy coding!

Comment: I use nodemon to make any change live immediately

Comment: Nice. It should open then. Could you share Angular code as well?

Comment: which part of the code..is quite complex (module..service..)